# How to connect consumer to Kafka topic with MassTransit using state machine

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

When there are two services:

Service 1 hosts state machine and produces message on topic. Service 2 should consume this message. How to setup this properly for Service 2 to consume messages?

When the code goes like this, it doesn't work:

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, SnakeCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance));

    mt.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.UsingKafka((ctx, kafka) =>
        {
            kafka.Host("kafka_url");
        });

        rider.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>()
            .Endpoint(e =>
            {
                e.Name = "queue_name";
                e.Temporary = false;
                e.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 8;
            });
    });
});
```

When I did it like this, it throws `System.ArgumentException: 'The consumer type was not found: OrderConsumer'`

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, SnakeCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance));

    mt.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.UsingKafka((ctx, kafka) =>
        {
            kafka.Host("kafka_url");

            kafka.TopicEndpoint<Null, OrderMessage>("queue_name", "group_id", cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                cfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(ctx);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think the .Endpoint() extension does anything with Kafka, so consider removing it. You do need AddConsumer() within the AddRider block though, or the exception you get will happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a mix of both samples you posted:

```
services.AddMassTransit(mt =>
{
    mt.UsingInMemory((context, cfg) => cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context, SnakeCaseEndpointNameFormatter.Instance));

    mt.AddRider(rider =>
    {
        rider.AddConsumer<OrderConsumer>()
        
        rider.UsingKafka((ctx, kafka) =>
        {
            kafka.Host("kafka_url");

            kafka.TopicEndpoint<Null, OrderMessage>("queue_name", "group_id", cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                cfg.ConfigureConsumer<OrderConsumer>(ctx);
            });
        });
    });
});
```